# Unix - detect if variable is a date dd.mm.yyyy

Tags: shell, unix

I am on ksh (Solris SunOS 5.10)

I have a variable  $VAR and want to write an if which runs code only if the variable matches the format dd.mm.yyyy

e.g 01.01.2009, 05.12.1998, etc.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
if [[ "${VAR}" == [0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] ]]; then
  echo "Variable matches format dd.mm.yyyy"
fi
```